# Large vertical column pushing down other grid elements

Tags: grid, html-table

I'm using Bootstrap to build a Dashboard, but I'm rather new to Bootstrap and I'm having issues getting the final grid layout in the image below. The problem is that when I add the 4th column (Table), which will vertically house more data than the other 3 columns on the left (Widgets), is pushing down the bottom row content (Chart) like in this image. It looks easy, and I guess it has something to do with the 'colspan' or 'rowspan' features, but I can't figure it out.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPJYw.jpg]

Why is my chart getting pushed down like this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to nest to achieve that.

For example:

```
<div class="container"
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 not-right-table-content">
      <!--nest content here, it's like a new grid-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          widget 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          widget 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          widget 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          chart
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          other content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      right table html here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nuno - Use below *"HTML Code Snippet"* or see my **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaadesh/nu4qejc2/)** (you might need to scroll boundaries to extend Result pane.)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 not-right-table-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">widget 1</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">widget 2</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">widget 3</div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">chart</div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">other content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">right table html here</div>
</div>
```

You can use below resources to know more about bootstrap:

- [Bootstrap - Approach to better, faster, stronger web development](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)
- [Blasting off with Bootstrap](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/blasting-off-with-bootstrap)